# User-defined function producing 'Could not find function' error

Tags: r, function

My dataset `test[[1]]` can be found [here](https://github.com/pourque/sampledata).

I'm defining a function and using it in a for loop in the following code. The function is supposed to concatenate strings such as `(test[[1]], '$', names(test[[1]])[1]))` before converting them into an R variable. So in this example, these strings go in and out comes `test[[1]]$V1`.

I then iterate the function over the variables in `test[[1]]`.

Unfortunately, I keep getting this error: `Error in stvar(test[[1]], j) <- NULL : could not find function "stvar<-"`.

```
stvar <- function(df,num) {
  eval(parse(text=paste(deparse(substitute(df)),'$',names(df)[num],sep='')))
}

for (j in 1:length(names(test[[1]]))){
  if (trimws(as.character(stvar(test[[1]],j)[1]))=="Div" & 
      grepl("^M",stvar(test[[1]],j)[3])==0) {
    stvar(test[[1]],j) <- NULL
  }
}
```

Also, not sure if this is important, but the for-loop finds columns containing certain characteristics (first observation == "Div", third observation doesn't start with 'M') and removes matching columns.

Is there a way I can make the loop recognize my function?

Comment: what if you remove `eval` from your function?

Comment: `eval(parse())` is just the wrong way to go. You can select `V1` just with `test[[1]][[names(test[[1]])[1]]]`. `[[` works with variables holding a character value specifying a column name. That's what you're supposed to use.

Comment: That csv file is kind of confusing. It has a bunch of names in both the first and second rows. The third row is just a bunch of "===" separators. There are two different columns that would be named "Div" after trimming whitespace.  A further serious problem is that you are describing the task only with code and it's pretty clear that you don't really have a good understanding of how to efficiently use R. So the task is completely unclear. And the error refers to code that is different than what you present.

Comment: Thanks @joran, this method works much better. 42, my task involves cleaning up this csv. What I've described above is an intermediate step, namely, finding the 'bad' "Div" column and removing it.

Comment: @42: sorry about the error; I noticed that it seemed to refer to test[1] rather than test[[1]] because I hadn't enclosed it in a code chunk. It does refer to the same code though.

Comment: You never defined a ‘stvar<-‘ function so trying to have that function on the LHS  of an assignment will fail.